# Dictionary not receiving the information of inputs

Tags: python, dictionary

i can't get the printing of a dict. to work, seen alot exsample codes but none have worked

```
from UI import ask_info
def main():
   mydict = {}
def add(mydict):
   info=ask_info()
   mydict=info
   for i in mydict:
      print(mydict[i])


def ask_info():
   info1=input("enter the info")
   info2=input("enter the info2")
   informations=mydict(info1,info2)
   return informations
```

the ask_info is in an different module, if i run this code the print is nothing also if write the dictionary into a file the file is empty. I also have tryed using a class module for this where i have refered to the class module in the "informations=class(info1,info2)" part

Comment: You don't seem to be `print`ing anything; what exactly is your problem?

Comment: forgot to add the print line, its in an another module

Comment: Then could you please edit the question, supplying the code that isn't working and what the problem is (Errors? Provide traceback. Unexpected outputs? Provide inputs, expected outputs, actual outputs).

Comment: So, what does `informations=mydic(info1, info2)` is intended to do?

Comment: its intended to return the inputs to the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, dictionaries in Python are not callable and don't work like that. Instead of `mydict(info1,info2)` you probably want something like `mydict[info1] = info2`.

Check [this link](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to see how dictionaries work. If you are creating a new dictionary, you can do something like `dict([(info1,info2)])` but it does not seem you are trying to do that.

Comment: Thanks alot! i figured how to make it work , made another module which asked the first info and returned it to the dict and then another which asks the second info and returns it to the dict. now the only problem i have is if i write the dict in a file it has the first info correct but the second info wrong , the second info should be integer number but it isn't showing up instead theres random numbers and letters